Local ASP.NET Core application running on iis
I have a laptop that is connected to an access point running on it local ASP.NET Core application on IIS server.
When I specify the gateway as 192.168.0.4, the server can be accessed (the application) from other laptops on the same network, but it has no internet connection. When I use 192.168.0.1 as gateway, the internet works, but the application can't be accessed from the other laptops.
What is the problem here and how to fix it?

168.0.1 is probably your router gateway,  or the router administrator IP, so that's most likely why you can't use that ip. So you have to reconfigure the router,  but then again I fail to see why you care or it matters to have the site run on 0.1 as opposed to 0.4? Having site on 0.4 should still eir

It looks like it's network related, I'm not sure what your intention is to change the gateway.
If you just want to access the site on the server from other machines, you just need to configure the firewall settings in the server to allow other machines to access the site with a specific port. Just like this article mentioned：Access Website Hosted In IIS On Windows 10 From Any PC On LAN
As far as I know, this firewall setting does not affect internet access on the server itself, so I suggest you can check it. But if I misunderstood something, please point it out to me.
